# How to assert form submission worked with capybara and minitest?

Tags: ruby, testing, capybara, minitest

I need to test that a form submits successfully and the user gets redirected to the proper page.

What is the best way to do this? The capybara readme suggests something like the following:

```rb
click_button 'Sign in'
assert_text 'Success'
```

But I find that unreliable and sometimes ambiguous. Is there any way to do something like the following?

```rb
assert_redirects_to after_sign_in_path do
  click_button 'Sign in'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
click_button 'Sign in'
assert_current_path after_sign_in_path
```

but you're now asserting your URL which really isn't relevant to the user, if you pick the string in your original example to be something that only exists on the page after logging in

```
assert_text "You've logged in"
```

you're at least asserting something relevant to the user (obviously the text is dependent on what your app shows). If it's "unreliable" then you need to figure out why it's unreliable - If it's that your page sometimes takes longer to log in then specify an extended maximum wait for that assertion

```
assert_text "You've logged in", wait: 10
```

etc.